# Making <th> vertical borders continue through entire table when <td> have different width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-table

I'm using Bootstrap tables to make a Gantt chart. My  for times are the same width.  For the  I have set the colspan="15" and inside of that I am putting a div and setting it to the width that I want.  What I want is the vertical borders from the  to continue through the entire body of the table, even though the  is a different width.  Is this possible?  Here is my code:

```
<div class="table-responsive gantt-chart">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Event</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th class="time">8am</th>
                <th class="time">9</th>
                <th class="time">10</th>
                <th class="time">11</th>
                <th class="time">12</th>
                <th class="time">1</th>
                <th class="time">2</th>
                <th class="time">3</th>
                <th class="time">4</th>
                <th class="time">5</th>
                <th class="time">6</th>
                <th class="time">7</th>
                <th class="time">8</th>
                <th class="time">9</th>
                <th class="time">10pm</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11:00 am</td>
                <td>Awesome party</td>
                <td>Party room</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:144px; width:48px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1:15 pm</td>
                <td>Test Event</td>
                <td>Home</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:252px; width:48px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3:15 pm</td>
                <td>Chad event</td>
                <td>tu casa</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:348px; width:72px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9:00 pm</td>
                <td>Randomness</td>
                <td>Random Hall</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:624px; width:72px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Table question stackoverflow]

The black lines I've drawn on there to indicate what I want to do with each section.  I'm not sure if this is possible or if I will need to find another way.  I'm using php to input the blue divs in the correct locations to match up to the time listed.

Comment: How is the class `time` defined? Does it have a specific width? (all the time cells seem to have the same width)

Comment: Sorry yes, they are set to a width of 48px each.

Comment: And then I'm using margin-left and width on the div inside the <td> to make it align under the correct time for the correct length (these are being calculated on the backend).

Comment: Knowing the width, you could have a background image for the table with the vertical bars. Let me prepare and post a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous solution (see below) fails in some cases, and you have already added jQuery to the project (needed by Bootstrap), here is another example of how it could be done with JavaScript and that may be better:

- Add the vertical bars dynamically (they could be `div`s)
- Place them behind the table
- Set the position according to each row
- Readjust their position when the page is resized.

Something like this (you can also [see it on this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8su2cr5m/1/)):

```js
function setVerticalBars() {

    var x = 0;
    
    // for each cell with a .time class
    $(".time").each(function() {

        // create the vertical line if it doesn't exist
        if (!$("#vertical-bar-" + x).length) {
            $(".mygantt").append('<div id="vertical-bar-' + x + '" class="vertical-bar"></div>');
        }

        // select the vertical bar associated to this cell
        var bar = $("#vertical-bar-" + x);

        // place it in he same position as the cell
        bar.css("left", $(this).position().left);

        // increase the counter to avoid duplicated id's
        x++;
    });
}

// adjust the divs on page load and when the page is resized
$(document).ready(setVerticalBars );
$(window).on("resize", setVerticalBars );
```

```css
/* make the odd trs semitransparent instead of gray (so you can see the bars through them) */
.mytable>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05) !important;
}

.mygantt .vertical-bar {
    width:1px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}

/* Styles from question */
th.time, td.time {
    width:48px;
}

.gantt-chart {
    position:relative;
}

.gantt-line {
    background:blue;
    height:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive gantt-chart mygantt">
    <table class="mytable table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Event</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th class="time">8am</th>
                <th class="time">9</th>
                <th class="time">10</th>
                <th class="time">11</th>
                <th class="time">12</th>
                <th class="time">1</th>
                <th class="time">2</th>
                <th class="time">3</th>
                <th class="time">4</th>
                <th class="time">5</th>
                <th class="time">6</th>
                <th class="time">7</th>
                <th class="time">8</th>
                <th class="time">9</th>
                <th class="time">10pm</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11:00 am</td>
                <td>Awesome party</td>
                <td>Party room</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:144px; width:48px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1:15 pm</td>
                <td>Test Event</td>
                <td>Home</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:252px; width:48px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3:15 pm</td>
                <td>Chad event</td>
                <td>tu casa</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:348px; width:72px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9:00 pm</td>
                <td>Randomness</td>
                <td>Random Hall</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:624px; width:72px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This solutions adjust betters to the table and the changes that could happen when the user resizes the window. I think it's better than the previous one, but I'll leave the old one below for reference.

---

### EDIT - Previous solution:

As I mentioned in the comments, one possible solution would be to add a background image to the `table` that mimics the vertical lines. That can be achieved with this:

```css
.mytable {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/8jNZRyf.png) repeat-y right top;
}
```

Now you need to fix one more issue: the Bootstrap `table-stripped` style has one row transparent and the next one gray. You will be able to see the vertical lines through only the even rows but not through the odd ones. To fix this, change the background of the odd lines from gray to a semitransparent color:

```css
.mytable>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05) !important;
}
```

And that should do the trick. You can see a demo on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8su2cr5m/

One problem with this solution: the background image will work as long as the cells have the expected width; if they don't (e.g.: when the table would occupy more than 100%, the cells may be resized so the table fits in the available space). A solution for this could be to calculate the width in JS and resize the background image accordingly.

Here's the full code for your case (you can see the issue that I specified in the paragraph above, but if you go full-screen then the issue is gone):

```css
/* set the table background to mimic the vertical bars bars */
.mytable {
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/8jNZRyf.png) repeat-y right top;
}

/* make the odd trs semitransparent instead of gray (so you can see the bars through them) */
.mytable>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05) !important;
}

/* Styles from question */
th.time, td.time {
  width:48px;
}

.gantt-line {
  background:blue;
  height:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive gantt-chart">
  <table class="mytable table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th class="time">8am</th>
        <th class="time">9</th>
        <th class="time">10</th>
        <th class="time">11</th>
        <th class="time">12</th>
        <th class="time">1</th>
        <th class="time">2</th>
        <th class="time">3</th>
        <th class="time">4</th>
        <th class="time">5</th>
        <th class="time">6</th>
        <th class="time">7</th>
        <th class="time">8</th>
        <th class="time">9</th>
        <th class="time">10pm</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11:00 am</td>
        <td>Awesome party</td>
        <td>Party room</td>
        <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
          <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:144px; width:48px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1:15 pm</td>
        <td>Test Event</td>
        <td>Home</td>
        <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
          <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:252px; width:48px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3:15 pm</td>
        <td>Chad event</td>
        <td>tu casa</td>
        <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
          <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:348px; width:72px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9:00 pm</td>
        <td>Randomness</td>
        <td>Random Hall</td>
        <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
          <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:624px; width:72px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick!  I never would have thought of using a background image to handle this. Much thanks.

Comment: I added a jQuery solution that may be better as it adjust to the table resizes (if any). I think it's better than the background image alternative

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setVerticalBars() {

    var x = 0;
    
    // for each cell with a .time class
    $(".time").each(function() {

        // create the vertical line if it doesn't exist
        if (!$("#vertical-bar-" + x).length) {
            $(".mygantt").append('<div id="vertical-bar-' + x + '" class="vertical-bar"></div>');
        }

        // select the vertical bar associated to this cell
        var bar = $("#vertical-bar-" + x);

        // place it in he same position as the cell
        bar.css("left", $(this).position().left);

        // increase the counter to avoid duplicated id's
        x++;
    });
}

// adjust the divs on page load and when the page is resized
$(document).ready(setVerticalBars );
$(window).on("resize", setVerticalBars );
```

```css
/* make the odd trs semitransparent instead of gray (so you can see the bars through them) */
.mytable>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05) !important;
}

.mygantt .vertical-bar {
    width:1px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}

/* Styles from question */
th.time, td.time {
    width:48px;
}

.gantt-chart {
    position:relative;
}

.gantt-line {
    background:blue;
    height:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive gantt-chart mygantt">
    <table class="mytable table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Event</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th class="time">8am</th>
                <th class="time">9</th>
                <th class="time">10</th>
                <th class="time">11</th>
                <th class="time">12</th>
                <th class="time">1</th>
                <th class="time">2</th>
                <th class="time">3</th>
                <th class="time">4</th>
                <th class="time">5</th>
                <th class="time">6</th>
                <th class="time">7</th>
                <th class="time">8</th>
                <th class="time">9</th>
                <th class="time">10pm</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11:00 am</td>
                <td>Awesome party</td>
                <td>Party room</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:144px; width:48px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1:15 pm</td>
                <td>Test Event</td>
                <td>Home</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:252px; width:48px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3:15 pm</td>
                <td>Chad event</td>
                <td>tu casa</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:348px; width:72px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9:00 pm</td>
                <td>Randomness</td>
                <td>Random Hall</td>
                <td class="gantt-section" colspan="15">
                    <div class="gantt-line" style="margin-left:624px; width:72px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```